# Update/Edit records in Hdfs using Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I have some records of people in HDFS. I use external table in Hive to view, to do my analytics on that particular data and also I can use it externally in other programs.

Recently I got an use case where I have to update the data in HDFS. As per documentation I got to know that we cant update or delete data using external table.

Another problem is the data is not ORC format. It is actually in TEXTFILE format. So I am unable to do update or delete data in internal table too. As it is in production I cant copy it to anywhere to convert it to ORC Format. Please suggest me how to Edit the data in HDFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Update or Delete using `INSERT OVERWRITE` + select from itself using filters and additional transformatins:

```
insert overwrite table mytable
select col1, --apply transformations here
       col2, --for example: case when col2=something then something_else else col2 end as col2
       ...
      colN
  from mytable
 where ... filter out records you want to delete
```

This approach will work for both External and Managed and for all storage formats. Just write select which returns required dataset and add INSERT OVERWRITE.